# Why cant I see my minecraft texture pack images?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How come when I go into my Texture pack assets, then Minecraft, then textures, then items, the pictures are just flowers. And not the texture pack images

Comment: Did you actually open the file? The minecraft textures are .png files, the default image of which is a picture of flowers

Answer (score 1):

### PC Version:

**Texture packs** were removed in version **1.6.1**, but information on them can still be found **[here.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Texture_pack)**

I assume, though, you meant **resource packs**, rather than **texture packs**.

Every resource pack has a file structure, containing file categories of e.g. items, models, which each contain the appropriate texture files. On Windows, by default, double-clicking a .png file (the default file format for texture files in resource packs) opens it in Windows Photo Viewer. You can use other software to view images, too. Most operating systems that have a user interface include built-in picture-viewing software that support .png file formats.

---

### Console Version:

I wouldn't expect any freedom on this topic, considering the texture packs are sold as downloadable content.